# str_replace() doesn't work using "(" and "[" PHP

Tags: php, html

This is my simple code function in php

```
function replaceCharact($input,$action){
    $output_1 = str_replace('(', "%11%", $input);
    $output_2 = str_replace(')', '%12%', $output_1);
    $output_3 = str_replace('[', '%13%', $output_2);
    $output_4 = str_replace(']', '%14%', $output_3);
    $output_5 = str_replace('"', '%15%', $output_4);
    $output_6 = str_replace('/', '%16%', $output_5);
    $output_7 = str_replace('"\"', '%17%', $output_6);
    $output_8 = str_replace('!', '%18%', $output_7);
    $output_9 = str_replace('<', '%19%', $output_8);
    $output_10 = str_replace('>', '%20%', $output_9);
    return $output_10;    
}
```

Only the `"!"($output_8)` change to %19%. The others output display nothing. Can you help me with this?

Comment: What's your goal with this function? Why not use a standard encoding function instead?

Comment: Additionally the code works as I'd expect, https://3v4l.org/Qfi7E. What are you doing with the `$action`? Maybe you went to minimal?

Comment: str_replace can take an array of replacements too, you don't need 10 different variables in a chain

Comment: Your code works fine here - https://3v4l.org/GBLWO (except for `'"\"'` as it results in `%15%\%15%` instead of `%17%`)

Comment: which should just be `'\\'`

Comment: I also can assure that this works all fine. Except `$output_7 = str_replace('"\"', '%17%', $output_6);` Which should actually be `$output_7 = str_replace('\\', '%17%', $output_6);`..

Comment: Thanks everyone I find the error!

Answer (score 1):

To simplify mass replacements using an array, try this...

```
$replacement = array(
  '(' => "%11%",
  ')' => '%12%',
  '[' => '%13%',
  ']' => '%14%'
  // etc etc
);

$string = str_replace( array_keys( $replacement ), $replacement, $string );
```

https://3v4l.org/kmXZp